# TypeError: $objectData is undefined - angular js

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting a strange error while working with factories and services. Here is my controller script

```
/*
 * 
 * 
 * AdvanceSettingsController
 * 
 * 
 */

angular.module('advanceSettings', [])

        .config([function () {

            }])


        .run(['$rootScope', 'CampaignsService', function ($rootScope, CampaignsService) {
                CampaignsService.init();
            }])


        //Common Ajax factory to make ajax requests and assign results in controller's scope
        .factory('AjaxRequests', ['$http', function ($http) {
                return {
                    getCampaignsData: function () {
                        return $http.get(SITEURL + 'tests/all_camp')
                    }
                }
            }])

        .service('CampaignsService', ['$rootScope', 'AjaxRequests', function ($rootScope, AjaxRequests) {

                this.init = function () {
                    this.$rowsData = {
                        items: []
                    };

                    AjaxRequests.getCampaignsData().success(function (response) {
                         this.$rowsData.items.push(response.campaigns);
                    })

                };

                this.getRows = function () {
                    return  this.$rowsData;
                }

            }])

        .controller('AdvanceSettingsController', ['$scope', 'CampaignsService', 'AjaxRequests', '$http', function ($scope, CampaignsService, AjaxRequests, $http) {
                $scope.CampaignsService = CampaignsService;
            }
        ])
        .value('version', '0.0.1-br.1');
;
'use strict';
```

In my view template I'm calling a service's function. like

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="row in CampaignsService.getRows() track by $index">

//My code

</div>
```

CampaignService's init function is being called at very first time and it initializes the this.$rowsData object. My question is, it's showing undefined error after success ajax call, why? I'm getting error `TypeError: this.$rowsData is undefined` 
If I initialize rowsData object after ajax success call, my code works but why I need to initialize over there. It's generally called a bad practice. Please suggest me the right way of doing that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be a scope conflict ... the scope inside `success` might be different from what you think it is. Try `var that=this` before the ajax call in your init function and then `that.$rowsData.items.push` inside the success callback

Comment: I've tried with that but get no success. Is there any guesses what I am missing ?